# Trying to draw polygons with JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I want to code a program in java that utilises loops and JFrame to create various polygons around one another.

ie. Triangle, then Square, then Pentagon etc...
[Refrence image of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9onF.png)

```
   super.paintComponent(g);
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    g2D.setPaint(Color.CYAN);
    Polygon p = new Polygon();
    for (int x = 4; x < 10; x++) {
            y = y + 50;
            z = z + 100;
            System.out.println("y = "+y);
            System.out.println("z = " + z);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                p.addPoint((int) (z + y * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / x)),
                        (int) (z + y * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / x)));
            }
            g2D.drawPolygon(p);
            
            }
        }
```

[Output of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3r4Q.png)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would create multiple loops. First one for the triangle, then one for the square and finally one for the pentagon. Each loop would use different angles. So get the triangle working, then the square and finally the pentagon. Don't try to write the entire code all at once. Once you get it working you will then likely be able to create a simple method where you pass in the starting point, and angle of rotation. Based on the angle of rotation you will know how many lines you need to draw.

Comment: Hello camickr. Thanks for your answer. I did try that but I didn't find a pattern. I searched on google and got this code for a pentagon using the trig functions (https://forum.level1techs.com/t/draw-a-hexagon-in-java/97617). I tried replicating it with loops, but the problem with trig graphs is that it will always repeat itself, which I suspect is happening. Do you think there is any way that I can break this repetition? Can you suggest another way or another pattern I can follow?

Your input is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd also not do this from within a paint pass, do this else where and cache the result, so that the paint pass executes as fast as possible

Comment: *but the problem with trig graphs is that it will always repeat itself,* - what do you mean "repeats" itself"? If you want to do a triangle you have a loop that does 3 iterations to give you 3 lines. How does that repeat itself? Post a proper [mre]. Check out [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/). The `ShapeUtils` class allows you to create each of the required shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

This is a picture of what the OP is supposed to draw.

[image]

The only regular polygon in the picture is the square.  At least, I think it's a square.

The triangle is an isosceles triangle.

I'm not sure how you would define the pentagon.  The five sides are not equal in length.  The side two segments are shorter than the bottom segment.  The top two segments appear to be longer than the bottom segment.

You can't use the center point and angle of rotation math to create the polygons.  The triangle is not an equilateral triangle.

You have to create this by calculating line segments.  I'm assuming that the three polygons share the same base.  Calculate one line segment at a time and test your code.  You're going to run hundreds of tests before you're done.

I'd start by calculating the square first.  A square is made up of four equal length line segments.  To start, I'd take 1/2 of the width of the drawing area to be the length of the line segment.  The first two X values are at the 1/4 and 3/4 points.  The Y value can be 20 pixels off the bottom.

Now that you've drawn one line segment, calculate the line segments for the square.  Draw the square.

Find the midpoint of the top square line segment.  calculate the triangle line segments.  Draw the triangle.

For the pentagon, the side line segments are shorter than the line segments of the square.  Each angle of a regular pentagon is 108 degrees from the previous line segment.  This polygon has slightly different angles at each point.

You'll have to experiment with the pentagon line segment lengths until the top two segments just intersect the square line segments.  You could probably do the math, but I suspect it would be easier to just keep guessing until you get an acceptable drawing.

Edited to add:

I created the following GUI.

[image]

Calculating the pentagon line segments took the most time.

The side line segments are 85% of the line length of the bottom line segment.  I used a 105 degree angle to calculate the end points of the side line segments.

I used a slope formula to calculate the y point of the top line segments.  I'd already calculated the start point and the intersect point to draw the pentagon side line segments and the square, respectively.  This calculation took most of my debugging time.

Edited to add:

I don't want to just give you the complete code.  Part of learning is struggling with the code and learning how to solve problems as they come up.  As I said, you should be writing a little bit of code at a time and testing each little bit of code to see what it does.

Here are two methods I wrote to calculate the four additional pentagon line segments.  The `Point` class is `java.awt.Point`.

```
    private Point calculateSideSegment(Point start, int radius, int angle) {
        double theta = Math.toRadians(angle);
        int x = (int) Math.round(Math.cos(theta) * radius) + start.x;
        int y = (int) Math.round(Math.sin(theta) * radius) + start.y;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
    
    private int calculateTopSegment(Point start, Point intersect, int x) {
        int yDiff = start.y - intersect.y;
        int xDiff1 = start.x - intersect.x;
        int xDiff2 = start.x - x;
        double slope = (double) yDiff / xDiff1;
        double y = Math.round(slope * xDiff2);
        return start.y - (int) y;
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your response. 

Can you please send me a snippet of your code for me to have a better understanding of what you mean?